# Understanding Python list and set

Tags: python

I am a learning Python by myself and thus I have this question. Based on below, I don't understand what `index` in the array `X` holds. Does it hold set or list or a combination of both?

```
X[index]= set([])
```

Comment: What does `type(X[index])` return?

Comment: `set([])` returns a set generated from an empty list.

Comment: I don't understand either since you never defined what `index` was. For all we know it could be literally anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`set` is a function which iterates the argument and adds elements to a set data structure, then returns the set object.

So in your example: when you call the set function here, you are passing in an empty list as the sole argument.  Python then iterates the empty list, adding *no* elements to a set data structure, and returns the set.

Therefore, `X[index]` will hold an empty set.

The following would also do the same, storing an empty set in `X[index]`:

```
X[index] = set()    # because the default set is the empty set
X[index] = set('')  # because it iterates the empty string!
X[index] = {x for x in []}  # "set comprehension" version
```

Comment: Thank you. Great explanation. Can I say set([]) forms a set of lists? for example, `( [1,2],[3,5], ...)`

Comment: Yes, you can say that.  But you would be incorrect.  In fact a set containing lists is impossible in python.